# Deployment Automation (Eclipse) from Command prompt

Tags: command-line, automation, eclipse

I want to automate the deployment in Eclipse through command prompt. Can I do it ?

Basically It open eclipse and when i need to right click and choose validate and once validation is completed, i need to right click and deploy.. Is there any way to convert the GUI operation from command line ? Or to do the mouse operation from Command line ?

Thanks and Regards !

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is better not to use Eclipse as a medium for short-term construction projects, and to draw attention to the original language in which they are written, and automation scripts that probably Ant. If your job easier, and the test is for complex projects, but only files, much more easier to work directly with the language compiler. The only useful thing you can do is to select other settings wrapper Eclipse with the option: eclipse.exe - launcher. Ini .

[The Eclipse runtime options, Command line arguments](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)